# Sets in $\sigma(E)\setminus E$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $S$ be a set and $E$ a subset of the powerset of $S$. We consider the sigma algebra generated by $E$. I wonder, what kind of sets are in the set $\sigma(E)\setminus  E $ . So everything in the generated sigma algbera on $E$, except the sets in $E$? Can anyone help me :) Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You cannot explicitly find all sets in the sigma algebra generated by the collection $E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to understand how to generate $\sigma(E)$ from $E$, we can define a sequence of families of sets $E_\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is a countable ordinal (so $\alpha < \omega_1$). Yes, this requires some set theory, which is unavoidable.

Define $E_0=E$ and having defined $E_\alpha$ we define

$$E_{\alpha+1} = \{ \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} A_n\mid \forall n: A_n \in E_\alpha\} \cup \{(S\setminus A) \mid A \in E_\alpha\}$$

and if we have defined $E_\alpha: \alpha < \beta$ where $\beta$ is a limit ordinal, define

$$E_\beta = \{\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} A_n \mid \forall n: \exists \alpha_n < \beta: A_n \in E_{\alpha_n}\} \cup \{(S\setminus A) \mid \exists \alpha < \beta: A \in E_\alpha\}$$

One can check that all $E_\alpha \subseteq \sigma(E)$, as we only use operations that $\sigma$-algebras are closed under on sets that have to be in $\sigma(E)$ already. And in fact $\sigma(A)=E_{\omega_1}$, so after uncountably many steps we "reach" $\sigma(E)$ taking countable unions and complements (and intersections too, by de Morgan).

In the case of the Borels sets on $\Bbb R^n$, every stage $\alpha$ gives new sets and we get a complicated [hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_hierarchy) of sets.

For simpler sets and families things can stabilise much faster (take the singletons as $E$ and we have the countable and co-counatable algebra in two steps, e.g.

Comment: So these sets are the unions and complements of sets in E? Which are not in E of course.

Comment: @SiemvanBenthem first unions and complements, then intersections of those unions and complements thereof and so on.